# Gson parsing a Json file

Tags: java, json, gson

i am trying to parse the following json file in java with gson:

[image]

So , I am trying to retrieve only the issues into a list of Issue. I have the following class to store the issue information:

[image]

But i got an error.. I am trying to get with the following but I think that i am so lost with this ( i am learning about this ) and i dont understand the error

[image]

any idea of how to do this? thank you so much!

Comment: What error are you actually getting? Unsafe cast?

Comment: Use code, not images

Comment: Where is the code !

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.get("issues")
```

will actually return a List Object, and not an Issue Object. You need to change the second parameter accordingly.